# Label Position Changed In VectorTile Service

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro

I made a map of boundies in ArcGIS Pro, labeled the polygon geometry by it's name. Everything is okay in ArcGIS Pro, but When I publish it to the ArcGIS Portal as a VectorTile Layer some of the label positions change.

[image: the map in ArcGIS Pro]

[image: the map in VectorTile Layer]